# Initialize the iterator variable in for loop in C

Tags: c

I'm sorry if it may be a stupid question. Last time, my friend told me that i should declare the iterator variable in the outside of the `for loop` when i develop on the embedded system, for example:

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   // Do something
}
```

should not use as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   // Do something
}
```

I ask him why but he just said "it's a tip".
Can someone give me some explications ?

I have short code below (one for initializing the iterator variable inside the for loop, one for out of for loop). Can you tell me what is better ?

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   // Do something
}

for (i = 0; i < 100,; i++) {
   // Do something
}

// Do something, but don't need to use variable `i`
```

another one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   // Do something
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100,; i++) {
   // Do something
}
```

I known that, when declare the iterator inside of `for loop`, it is limited in the scope of `for loop`. Are there something important in two cases ?

Comment: I guess that he thinks that it reduces the amount of memory allocation cycles during runtime, but any compiler will automatically optimise any iterator variable for all of the for loops into one variable anyway.

Comment: In some compilers the variable declared inside the `for` loop has a larger scope of the block containing the loop. In this case if you try to use the same name in two different loops you'll get an error that the variable is already declared. This is, however, a bug, but it happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule, the best practice is to declare the variable in the `for` loop. It avoids confusion and gives the compiler more opportunities for optimization.

The only time to declare in an outer scope is if you need to use the variable again - say loop until you hit a certain criterion, then pick up from where you left off in another loop.

Historically, there was an issue here, in that before standardization of the language, different compilers would treat the scope of the loop iterator differently.

In the following code it would vary where `i` goes out of scope:

```
void func(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        ...
    } // Some compilers have i going out of scope on the last loop iteration

    int j = i;  // So in some compilers this is valid, others not
} // Other compilers i goes out of scope here
```

Thus it was more portable to write:

```
void func(void)    
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        ...
    } 

    int j = i;  // Valid on all compilers
} //  i goes out of scope here on all compilers
```

Because declaring your loop counter early was more portable. But this was standardized to being the tigther scope back in the 90s, so it's not really an issue now.

Comment: If i have many `for loop`, for example 1000 for loop,  the variable `i` is used just for iteration counter, as you said `As a general rule, the best practice is to declare the variable in the for loop. It avoids confusion and gives the compiler more opportunities for optimization`, so i should declare the iterator variable for loop, is it better ?

Comment: @Hitokiri Just declare it in the for loop as you were doing originally. If your friend cannot give you a better explanation or reason than "it's a tip", then there's no good reason to pay attention to it.

Answer (score 2):

Did a quick check with a simple loop and the `sdcc` compiler for Pic16 (that is what I have and generally use), and used:

```
void plop () {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        i=i+1;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
        i=i+1;
    }
}


void main (){
    plop;
}
```

which gives a code size of 136 bytes/68 words, and

```
void plop () {
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        i=i+1;
    }
    for (i=0; i<100; i++){
        i=i+1;
    }
}


void main (){
    plop;
}
```

which gives a code size of 132 bytes/66 words.

So, if you're really tight on program space, ...